# Left luggage facilities in train stations in France or sending luggage from France to Spain?

Tags: trains, france, luggage, spain, luggage-storage

After some time in Nice, I'm doing the Camino 'Le Puy - Pamplona' track (5-6 week walk) and was hoping to leave the rest of my luggage in a train station either in Lyon or Nice.

Does anyone know if you can leave it this long?

And if so, will it cost the earth?

Alternatively, does anyone know a way to send my luggage to my final destination (Pamplona or San Sebastien in Spain) and have it stored there which would save me travelling all the way back?

Comment: Is that a fairly well known walking route? If so, it may be worth looking for companies that specialise in the route, who'd be set up to store and then forward your stuff

Answer (score 5):

Can you not just send it to some friends or neighbors in Pamplona/San Sebastien? I guess it wont make sense to send it to your own address since you wont be there to pick it up.

[sendmybag](http://www.sendmybag.com/_storage.htm?iframe=true&width=700&height=470) has a service to deliver your items from a storage to you, this is maybe something you can do when you arrive in Spain.

Alternatively you could check out [www.couchsurfing.org](http://www.couchsurfing.org) or [www.hospitalityclub.org](http://www.hospitalityclub.org) for someone who you trust with your belongings to send it to you later.

Answer (score 3):

You can look up services in the main French train stations on the [Gares en Mouvement](http://www.gares-en-mouvement.com/en) (“stations in motion”) site. Unfortunately, [Nice](http://www.gares-en-mouvement.com/en/frnic/services-en-gare/services/) doesn't have a left luggage facility. [Lyon Part-Dieu](http://www.gares-en-mouvement.com/en/frlpd/services-en-gare/services/) has one.

If you're staying in a hotel, ask if you can leave your luggage for a few days. Some places will accept, others won't.

I doubt that you'll find a decently priced way of shipping luggage ahead, this kind of service has disappeared.